# How to include jar dependency classes in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We are building one jar and that jar depending on many jars. Currently we are adding dependency jars explicitly like below.

```
  compile files('libraries/amqp-client-3.1.3.jar') 
  compile files('libraries/antisamy-1.5.1.jar') 
  compile files('libraries/antlr-2.7.7.jar') 
  compile files('libraries/aopalliance-1.0.jar')
```

So, instead of adding all the dependency jars explicitly, we need to take required classes from dependency jars and those should be included as part of jar preparation. Can any one tell me how to achieve? thanks.

Comment: For me this question is quite unclear. Can You clarify a bit or maybe provide a minimal working example explicitly showing what's not working?

Comment: @Opal, we are building our project as one jar and this jar required dependency classes from the above mentioned external jars. Here, instead of mentioning external jars we are planning to take required classes and those classes to be included as of project jar preparation and that generated jar should run without depending on external jars.

Comment: Is fatjar plugin what You're looking for?

Comment: not sure... reading what fatjar plugin will do...

Comment: after extracting all the jars into one folder and built single jar, when I use this single jar, couldn't able to find packages and getting compilation errors. It seems like may not doing proper extraction from the jars as am extracting manually. Does gradle provide extracting all the jars and placing into single folder? I have seen zipTree, but it could extract only one jar at a time. I am looking for an API where it can extract multiple jars.

Comment: You can iterate over collection of jars and extract every element on the collection. Or use https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your build system, you want the shade plugin (maven): http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ or the shadow plugin (gradle): https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

If you are using ant, I would try to leverage the maven plugin: http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html

However, see the warnings in my answer here: [Gradle shadow jar with conflicting dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040813/gradle-shadow-jar-with-conflicting-dependencies/29497182#29497182)